# Заполнить объект другим объектом

Tags: javascript

Есть один объект вида:

```
obj1 = [
1,
2,
3,
4
]
```

Он динамический, в нем может быть 4 числа, 5, 100...

Эти значения необходимо проставить в другой объект вида (создать объект на основе первого):

```
obj2 = [
    {
      text: '1',
      value: '1',
    },
    {
      text: '2',
      value: '2',
    },
    {
      text: '3',
      value: '3',
    },
    {
      text: '4',
      value: '4',
    },
  ];
```

Т.е. во втором объекте должно быть столько значений, сколько было в первом.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать. Нет идей :((

Comment: `const obj2 = obj1.map(v => ({text: v, value: v}));`

Comment: Нет идей?) Почитайте учебник... https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration https://learn.javascript.ru/while-for

Comment: Это не объекты... Это массивы. ;)

Answer (score 3):

```js
const obj1 = [
  1,
  2,
  3,
  4,
];

console.log(obj1);

const obj2 = obj1.map(value => ({
  text: value.toString(),
  value: value.toString(),
}));

console.log(obj2);
```